# openlayers web app porting to iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, gis, openlayers

I want to develop an application for iOS and android which monitors user current location and  show local notifications/alerts to the user when user enters a  boundary defined in application .

I am  planning to choose openlayers java script library  to  build the web application and port it to iOS and Android using cordova .

I would like to know if someone has ever used corodova to port GPS applications which can track user's current location while  running  app in the background ( actually run as services because user may exit the application and still able to receive local-notifications).

Please let me know if there are any limitations in  using cordova over native app in this specific case .   Thank you